# iisnode: Publish an application inside an existing one

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I'm trying to run two node applications, one inside another in IIS to have the proper rote:

```
http://server/node1
http://server/node1/node2
```

I have this scenario in my IIS:

```
Default Web Site
    - node1
        - node2
```

The struggle is that the first application node (node1) works fine, but the second keep giving me **Status Code 500**, however when I deploy it outsite the virtual directory (node1) works, like this:

```
Default Web Site
    - node1
    - node2
```

This is the web.config that I'm using:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- for node1 -->
        <add key="DEPLOY_PATH" value="/node1" />
        <!-- for node2 -->
        <add key="DEPLOY_PATH" value="/node1/node2" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewrite">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <iisnode maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="1000" namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="25000" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="node_modules" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I couldn't find anything on the web about it, or similar work. I want to know why the node2 application doesn't work when deployed inside node1.